# javascript call to open multiple windows, but only one opens

Tags: javascript

I've a javascript that opens a set of windows.

```
    $.each($('input.ListCheckBox:checked:not(#ToggleCheckBox)'), function (idx, item) {
        var $Url = $UrlTemplate.replace('{{id}}', $(item).val());
        window.open($Url, '_blank');
    });
```

When I run it locally if works fine. When I publish it an run it from production only one windows/tab opens. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Give a different name for each window instead of "_blank".

Comment: Why does it work locally and not in production. What is the difference ?

Comment: @Teemu — `_blank` is a special name meaning "no name"

Comment: @Quentin Yep, I know, it's just maybe all browsers are not respecting it ..? I've had no problems when opening multiple windows with "_blank", though.

Comment: And now I'm going to hide under a rock. Did not notice the litle 'pop-ups blocked' icon. Just accept pop-ups for this site and it all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers don't like opening multiple new tabs to prevent ads from doing it. In chrome every user interaction can only open one new tab.

Comment: when I run the project from VS in debug. Chrome actually does open all the requested windows. It is not good practice, but it is a temporarily workaround to help a customer.

Answer (score -1):

The remark of @sebastian is correct. In chrome any interaction can just open one windows. But I'd like to add that 2nd, 3th, ... window.open calls are just waiting to get an approval by the pop-up blocking mechanism. If you approve pop-ups from your site in the browser it works fine. For a production application you'll need to add some kind of warning to the users so that they actually do accept those multiple pop-ups for your application.